# Freeradius Server using 100% cpu

Tags: mysql, freeradius, radius

So I set up a server for free radius and right now I have around 1k users that try to use hotspot that connect to my server when there are more than 400 users that active the local hotspot having problem such as the users cannot log in to the server and sometimes free radius have a duplicate entry in radacct tables and that causing the user's session time to reduced twice from it should ..

sorry for my English... I know that we need to launch the free radius in debug mode to know the exact reason why but, right now we can't really do that because the server is being used most of the time by users

below are the screenshot of the server and also one of the hotspot that are being used by user's

[image: radius]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would like to update this, so I have run the debug mode and found that one of my nas (Mikrotik that connected to my Radius Server ) are sending multiple requests and those requests are being processed again and again by the radius server, so I reset the Mikrotik and set timeout so the router wont sending multiple request that would hammer the radius